# New sink installation: garbage disposal sits lower and p-trap no longer at the right height for the drain

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, garbage-disposal

I'm completely new with basic plumbing, but last ngiht after my new sink went in I tried reattaching the garbage disposal and new faucet. It wasn't too bad but the disposal sits a little lower than before so the p-trap no longer connects to the drain. See the image:

[image]

How do I go about attaching these parts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [reversible p-trap](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Oatey-1-1-2-in-Plastic-P-Trap-with-Reversible-J-Bend-P9703WBG/203704127)

[image]

would allow you use an [extension](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Keeney-1-1-2-in-Plastic-Slip-Joint-Extension-Tube/1071497) attached to the black elbow on the disposal. By using the reversible trap you are moving the long part of the trap to the j pipe side and creating distance on the disposal side that you then fill with and extension.

Comment: Could probably get away with reversing the J they already have, though the sharp angle might not be the best thing when flow is reversed.

Comment: Looks like you might just be able to "horse" it on there....

Answer (score -1):

You will need to either shorten the tailpipe from the drain to the disposal if possible, get an extension, or buy a replacement p-trap setup.

Comment: Is this not the same answer as above?